# How to reflect product price and quantity changes on journal entries of an invoice

Tags: odoo, wizard, invoice, odoo-13

I create a wizard that change price and quantity for each product but the amount_untaxed, tax_amount and total amount unchanged and journal entries are unbalanced. how to resolve that?

Comment: Can you show your relevant code?

Comment: This is the function when button pressed                                                                               https://bpaste.net/UPRQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `_onchange_price_subtotal()` on every changed invoice line (model `account.move.line`) to trigger the recomputation. The recomputation is only implemented for changes in the view, that's why it's isn't triggered when using a wizard. But the implementation can be used in the wizard, too, without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

**strong text**_onchange_price_subtotal doesn't work. But

```
current_invoice_lines = rec.order_id.line_ids.filtered(lambda line: not line.exclude_from_invoice_tab)
others_lines = rec.order_id.line_ids - current_invoice_lines
    if others_lines and current_invoice_lines - rec.order_id.invoice_line_ids:
        others_lines[0].recompute_tax_line = True
        rec.order_id.line_ids = others_lines + rec.order_id.invoice_line_ids
        rec.order_id._onchange_recompute_dynamic_lines()
```

After adding the above code on account.move ... journal entries are balanced but tax_amount still unchanged?